# Timer for label in c#

Tags: c#, timer, label

I´m working on game in C#. I have read something about the timers for displaying the labels.

This should be just a warning label. I´ve tried `Thread.Sleep` and hiding the label afterwards, but it is hidden earlier then it is shown.

Is there any other possibilty to do this?
Thank you.

```
labelTwiceRestart.Visible = true;
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
labelTwiceRestart.Hide();

return;
```

Comment: What you're seeing is the application freezing before it's able to update the label visibility, then unfreezing and immediately hiding the label.  So you aren't seeing the label appear.  Yes, a timer would help you here.  But you need to focus on improving the quality of your question.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to achieve. It seems that you should be using a `Timer`, because `Thread.Sleep` will block your UI thread for these 5 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timer_tick, then control the program and the label to show and hide.

Go to your toolbox, then double click on timer, then change the property to your needs.

Double click the timer to add the functionality of the timer.

Comment: Auto correct, I am using a cellphone. It should of came out like my edit.

Comment: Sorry about that I fixed my answer